# Regex extract string in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract a string from a String in Regex Java

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((.|\\n)*).{4}InsurerId>\\S*.{5}InsurerId>((.|\\n)*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(abc);
```

I'm trying to extract the value between

```html
<_1:InsurerId>F2021633_V1</_1:InsurerId>
```

I'm not sure where am I going wrong but I don't get output for

```
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([^:]+:InsurerId)>([^<]*)</\\1>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(abc);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pB0fK9/4)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the totally awesome page http://regex101.com/ to test your regular expressions. As you can see at https://regex101.com/r/rV8uM3/1, you only have empty capturing groups, but let me explain to you what you did. :D

- `((.|\n)*)` This matches any character, or a new line, unimportant how often. It is capturing, so your first matching group will always be everything before `<_1:InsurerId>`, or an empty string. You can match any character instead, it will include new lines: `.*`. You can even leave it away as it isn't actually part of the String you want to match - using anything here will actually be a problem if you have multiple InsurerIds in your file and want to get them all.
- `.{4}InsurerId>` This matches "InsurerId>" with any four characters in front of it and is exactly what you want. As the first character is probably always an opening angle bracket (and you don't want stuff like "<ExampleInsurerId>"), I'd suggest using `<.{3}InsurerId>` instead. This still could have some problems (<Test id="<" xInsurerId>), so if you know exactly that it's "_<a digit>:", why not use `<_\d:InsurerId>`?
- `\S*` matches everything except for whitespaces - probably not the best idea as XML and similar files can be written to not contain any space at all. You want to have everything to the next tag, so use `[^<]*` - this matches everything except for an opening angle bracket. You also want to get this value later, so you have to use a capturing group: `([^<]*)`
- `.{5}InsurerId>` The same thing here: use `<\/.{3}InsurerId>` or `<\/_\d:InsurerId>` (forward slashes are actually characters interpreted by other RegEx implementations, so I suggest escaping them)
- `((.|\n)*)` Again the same thing, just leave it away

---

The resulting Regular Expression would then be the following:

```
<_\d:InsurerId>([^<]*)<\/_\d:InsurerId>
```

And as you can see at https://regex101.com/r/mU6zZ3/1 - you have exactly one match, and it's even "F2021633_V1" :D

For Java, you have to escape the backslashes, so the resulting code would look like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<_\\d:InsurerId>([^<]*)<\\/_\\d:InsurerId>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7 and above, you can use naming groups to make the Regex a little bit more readable (also see the backreference group \k for close tag to match the openning tag):

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:<(?<InsurancePrefix>.+)InsurerId>)(?<id>[A-Z0-9_]+)</\\k<InsurancePrefix>InsurerId>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<_1:InsurerId>F2021633_V1</_1:InsurerId>");

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group("id"));
    }
```

Using back reference the matches() fails, for example, on this text

```
<_1:InsurerId>F2021633_V1</_2:InsurerId>
```

which is correct

Javadoc has a good explanation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Also you might consider using a different tool (XML parser) instead of Regex, as well, as other people have to support your code, and complex Regex is usually difficult to understand.